# PGSQL: Get space taken up by a Geometry object in database

Tags: postgresql

How do I get the amount of space taken up by a `Geometry` object stored in a PostgreSQL database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it to the [`pg_column_size()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE) function.